# Random.Range not working with integer, why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

*So I'm doing this project of a lock picking, it's really simple but I'm having some problems with the Random.Range it doesn't change when I press the keys that i set up. My Scene is really simple, I have a door with the script in it, and Unity's First Person Controller. 
I want the Random.Range change the value when I press the keys 1 to 9 then it prints both, and if they are equal or greater the collider.isTrigger is set to true.*

```
#pragma strict

public var playerrangel : int = 0;
public var  lockStrength : int = 1;

function Update () 
{  
    if (playerrangel == lockStrength || playerrangel >lockStrength){    
    // if both Ranges of player and lock are  equal or greater then it sets Door Trigger to true.

    collider.isTrigger = true;
    print ("Door unlocked!");

}
else  {                                                 
    // if both Ranges of player and lock aren't  equal or greater then it sets Door Trigger to false.

   collider.isTrigger = false;

}

// The player enters range of the lock  - 1 to 9.

if (Input.GetKeyDown ("1")) {       
    // Select Range 1

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("2")) {    
    // Select Range 2

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");

}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("3")) {     
    // Select Range 3

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");


}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("4")) {    
    // Select Range 4

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");

}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("5")) {   
    // Select Range 5

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");


}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("6")) {   
    // Select Range 6

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");

}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("7")) {   
    // Select Range 7

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");

}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("8")) {   
    // Select Range 8

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");

}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("9")) {   
    // Select Range 9

    print (playerrangel + " Player Range");
    print (lockStrength  + " Lock Strength");

}
}

function OnTriggerEnter () {

    playerrangel = Random.Range(1,30);
    lockStrength = Random.Range(1,40);
```

### }

I got another question about it, what can I do for when the door is unlocked the Input.GetKeyDown turns off so the player can't change it back to false and to print only one time the "Door Unlocked!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the Random.Range function again when you want it to change. OnTriggerEnter will only be called when the collision starts. I suggest something like this instead:

```
int range = 0;
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("5")) {   // Select Range 5
    range = 5;
else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("6")) {   // Select Range 6
    range = 6;

if (range != 0)
{
    int playerrangel = Random.Range(1,30);
    int lockStrength = Random.Range(1,40);
    // now do something with these values
}
```

For your other question, you cannot turn off `Input.GetKeyDown`, but you can skip the function where the check occurs: `if (!doorOpened) CheckInput();`. Then obviously, you set `doorOpened=true;` after the player is successful.